# Can I locate the Token Holder

Tags: tokens

I sent a large amount of UTK to Coinbase (stupidly).
The Hash is `0xdc3e9a82c4aac374cc8ee76c840401cdaee2b0677d9d54ac86bbd820af2bfc7f`.
The new holder's address is `0xae14f2ebb89b14ac6e98876516a884ebbc77a1ae`.
I appreciate you are all busy but I am new to this and just need to know **is it lost or is there any hope?**
Thanks.
MJC

Comment: I am not an expert but I don't think it's possible to identify someone using their address. Since you sent the tokens specifically to given address, you must have come across that address somehow. IMHO that's the only way but don't give up hope yet.

Answer (score 1):

You say you sent it to CoinBase. If that’s the case, then the address you’re referencing probably belongs to Coinbase. (Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but that seems reasonable.) Your only real hope, if that’s the case, is to contact CoinBase’s technical support. But I doubt that will help because how will they know that you are who you say you are?  It’s a weird anonymous space for better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

This address doesn't show any activity. As I can see on etherscan there were [no transactions](https://etherscan.io/address/0xae14f2ebb89b14ac6e98876516a884ebbc77a1ae) sent from this address and it only has tokens that you sent.

In a very extreme scanario when you can use machine learning and different algorithms to find out who this person is you should have a transaction history, but if no such is given it is not possible to identify the person behind this account. This is what blockchain is about.

But still, you can leave a comment on Etherscan in [this section](https://etherscan.io/address/0xae14f2ebb89b14ac6e98876516a884ebbc77a1ae#comments) and just hope that the person will answer you and still as it was mentioned by another answer, it is hard to identify yourself, but you can try to use some money exchange history when you were buying these tokens. 
 Have a good luck.

---

**Afterword**

*I was thinking of this kind of issues some time ago and for security reasons there should be a way to monitor this account and to wait while it will transfer tokens to another address or try to use some kind of exchange to withdraw money from account so you can identify the person behind the account, but this is still theory and I don't know about legal and technical background of this algorithm. There are many details.*